# Can't mapping boolean value with added new column in hibernate annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, annotations

```
@Column(columnDefinition="boolean default false")

public boolean getusernameChange() {
    return usernameChange;
}
public void setusernameChange(boolean usernameChange) {
    this.usernameChange =usernameChange;
}
```

The above method is implemented with `@Entity` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the old column and update with the following `@Column` annotation

```
 @Column(name="USER_CHANGE", columnDefinition = "tinyint default false")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
private Boolean usernameChange = false;

public Boolean getUsernameChange() {
    return this.usernameChange;
}

public void setUsernameChange(Boolean usernameChange) {
    this.usernameChange = usernameChange;
}
```

Comment: Hi, i already tried this method. Once i get the initial database value and end user change the state then i update the value into database using session.merge() method. But, the updated Boolean data does not reflect on the database.  The hibernate configuration file using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update

Comment: hmmm...i have an entity with field

 @Column(name = "issystem", nullable = false, unique = false)
 @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
 private Boolean isSystem;

**hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update**
update field via **sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(obj)**
 and it works.
maybe drop column and launch hibernate with it